# How to get users and groups for a particular approle in Azure using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

In my powershell script, I have used Get-AzADApplication (from Az.resources module) to get an Enterprise Application. I can see the particular approle I am interested in (with an ID) in the result. How can I then get all the users and groups that has the appRoles?

From the portal, looks like ManagedApplications//AppRoleAssignments was used to fetch that info. What's the powershell equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below powershell command to retrieve the application role assignments for a service principal.

> Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $ServicePrincipalId

Below image shows the users assigned the app roles.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> To get all the users and groups that has the appRoles:

***Use below command to achieve the expected results.***

***For Users:***

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object {$_.objecttype -eq "User"} | select RoleDefinitionName,ObjectType,DisplayName
```

[image]

***For Groups:***

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object {$_.objecttype -eq "Group"} | select RoleDefinitionName,ObjectType,DisplayName
```

[image]

Refer [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-9.7.1) Azure PowerShell Command.